# Facebook SDK Swift doesn't code hint while Parse's SDK does

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

something strange going on, I want to interact with the Facebook and Parse SDK in Swift, so I installed both trough cocoapods pre. I created one Bridge-Header.h file, with these contenst:

```
#ifndef Pawky_Bridge_Header_h
#define Pawky_Bridge_Header_h

#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

#endif
```

After that I went to my build settings and pointed my Objective-C bridging header under code generation to this file. It finds them both because if I would append any character to FacebookSDK it won't build (FacebookSDK/FacebookSDKs.h for instance throws an error). **And I get parse code hinting in my code, I can work with the SDK but I don't get anything for Facebook..** So Parse is working but I can't get Facebook to work. I already tried downloading the SDK manually and importing it but the same problem...

Someone a clue? 
Thanks

Comment: Can you add the errors to your question?

Comment: well there aren't any, if I change the name of the Facebook SDK to <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDKs.h> it throws me a file not found error, but with the right name it finds it and compiles it, so that's why I'm confused I don't get any code hinting!

Comment: Okay interesting thing I noticed, it all works when I use my xcproject file, but as soon as I my xcworkspace file instead it stops working. I installed other frameworks using cocoapods pre, nothing that has to do with Facebook though..

Comment: Even if I add everything through cocoapods, all of them work but Facebook.. This is what my podfile looks like:
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.6.3'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.23.0'
pod 'Snap'

Comment: so there is no autocomplete...but does it compile?

if it does, the 'easy' thing might just be to shut down xcode and start it again.

Comment: @iamdavidlam well it compiles with the SDK included but i can't use any of it methods, then it says unknown object and does not compile..